# Find HTML ID of a nested element using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a grid using  and  elements.  Each row is represented by a div, and each cell within the row is represented by a span like this:

```
<div id="row1">
    <span id="cell1"></span>
    <span id="cell2"></span>
    <span id="cell3"></span>
</div>
<div id="row2">
    <span id="cell1"></span>
    <span id="cell2"></span>
    <span id="cell3"></span>
</div>
<div id="row3">
    <span id="cell1"></span>
    <span id="cell2"></span>
    <span id="cell3"></span>
</div>
```

I want to be able to access each cell by its ID.  Say for example I wanted to access the middle cell, row2, cell2.  How can I access that specific cell using JS?  Thanks!

Comment: First of all ID should be unique, so you can only use ID for one element. You cannot use repeated ID values.

Comment: You also didn't post any attempts at solving your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, IDs have to be unique across a document. You should be using a class here.

After that, you can get the element by its parent ID and its own class.

```
document.getElementById('row2').getElementsByClassName('cell2')[0]; // the first .cell2 in #row2
```

Or, simpler, if this is the only time you have these classes:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('cell2')[1]; // the second .cell2 in the document
```

If you don't care about old IE versions, you can also do:

```
document.querySelector('#row2 .cell2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ids are supposed yo be unique. What you wrote in your html wouldn't work. What you can do, however, is to have a class "row" and "cell", and browse them one-by-one using for example this jquery syntax

```
var where = $("#where_you_start")
for(var i=0; i++; i<how_many_rows_forward){
    //Do some stuff on the current row
    where = where.next(".row")
}
```

(It's possible to to that without jquery of course)

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else, you should know ID attribute of html elements was designed to be unique on the page, so, is not good to have multiple elements sharing the same id, I would use classes instead

```
<div id="row1">
  <span class="cell1"></span>
  <span class="cell2"></span>
  <span class="cell3"></span>
</div>

<div id="row2">
  <span class="cell1"></span>
  <span class="cell2"></span>
  <span class="cell3"></span>
</div>

<div id="row3">
  <span class="cell1"></span>
  <span class="cell2"></span>
  <span class="cell3"></span>
</div>
```

To access your cell, you can use JQuery, this way:

```
$("#row2 .cell2");
```

Or, in pure javascript

```
document.querySelector("#row2 .cell2")
```

What you can do from here depends on what jQuery offers in the first option, and what the bare browser API can do in the second.
I recommend using jQuery because of the simplicity and the cross-browser support